# Unable to Remove ;jsessionid in a Spring Boot / Web Flow Application's URL when Deployed to Tomcat 8.5

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, cookies, spring-webflow, jsessionid

I'm working on a Java application where a user registers a password for his/her account. The following are being used:

- Spring Boot
- Spring MVC
- Spring Web Flow
- Spring Security
- Thymeleaf
- Interceptor (for checking the session in the `preHandle` method)

---

For the Spring Security part, there's really no authentication required. I just use it to handle CSRF and the configuration is as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      // CSRF feature only
      http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
   }

}
```

---

Now, this is where things get messy. When I deploy it to Tomcat in a Unix environment, `;jsessionid` gets appended to the URL and Spring Security is not happy. I have scrounged the Internet and found the following solutions to remove it (alongside my results).

---

`server.servlet.session.tracking-modes=cookie` in **`application.properties`** does nothing.

---

**`web.xml`**

```xml
<session-config> 
   <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode> 
</session-config>
```

**or**

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {

   @Override
   public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
      HashSet<SessionTrackingMode> set = new HashSet<>();
      set.add(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE);
      servletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(set);
   }

}
```

yields an `IllegalArgumentException: The session tracking mode [COOKIE] requested for context [/<context-name>] is not supported by that context`

---

I'm about to pull what remains of my hair off so I reverted any `cookie`-related changes and thought of just allowing semicolons in the URL (I know, I know, not secure) using the snippet below in the same `SecurityConfig` class.

```java
   @Bean
   public HttpFirewall allowUrlSemicolonHttpFirewall() {
      StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
      firewall.setAllowSemicolon(true);
      return firewall;
   }

   @Override
   public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
      super.configure(web);
      web.httpFirewall(allowUrlSemicolonHttpFirewall());
   }
```

And voila! The web flow runs on an infinite redirect.

---

**Questions:**

- Has anyone ever encountered `IllegalArgumentException: The session tracking mode [COOKIE] requested for context [/<context-name>] is not supported by that context` before? I've searched far and wide and the closest that I could find is [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12058).
- Could the reason behind `server.servlet.session.tracking-modes=cookie` not working be the same as above?
- Could the infinite redirect be caused by `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()`? I tried using `anonymous()` but the result was the same.
- Is it possible to know which part exactly is causing the infinite redirect?

---

Please note that allowing semicolons in the URL is working fine and dandy in my `localhost`, so I have a hunch that what's causing the redirects is SSL-related. In the same way that locally `;jsessionid` is not being appended to the URL.

My next step is to try configuring SSL locally in an attempt to replicate the issue. In the meantime, any help would be highly appreciated. My apologies if there's too much information here; I'm willing to repost it as multiple questions if that's necessary.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the session cookie is, indeed, being sent and accepted? That is, might it be falling back to URL rewriting because the cookie isn't working? And, could that be if there is a redirect from http to https, and it's a Secure cookie?

Comment: @dbreaux First of all, thanks for editing the post and taking the time to reply! I haven't really _directly_ dealt with cookies before and have a lot of questions right now, but perhaps I'll start with this one: By a session cookie being sent and accepted, are you saying that I need to manually set one on top of the configuration in `application.properties` or `web.xml`?

Comment: No manual steps in the application. Just by virtue of using Spring Web Flow, you're using HTTP Sessions in Tomcat, which use a jsessionid cookie by default. But Tomcat might have that cookie set like for Secure-only, for instance. Would be something to check in Tomcat.

Comment: Hello. Did you eventually manage to fix this?

Comment: Hi @SmalisSklavos. Dunno if you still need it, but yes, we recently did. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77518312/1705048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this one myself as further development this year actually led to a solution from a teammate of mine when he extended the base code to a new application which required Spring Security. Turns out the persistent `jsessionid` in our case was due to the `cookies` attribute below in our Tomcat `context.xml`.

```xml
<Context useHttpOnly="true" cookies="false" reloadable="false">
```

On the Java side, the generic security configuration below (for the original application) worked even with the Tomcat configuration above.

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnExpression;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@ConditionalOnExpression("${permit.all:true}")
public class SecurityConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.antMatchers("/**").permitAll())
                .csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.ignoringAntMatchers("/**"))
                .sessionManagement().enableSessionUrlRewriting(true)
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS);

        LOGGER.debug("Default {} loaded", SecurityConfig.class.getSimpleName());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        DefaultHttpFirewall firewall = new DefaultHttpFirewall();
        return web -> web.httpFirewall(firewall);
    }

}
```